# How to access the child elements of a TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I am trying to add a search feature to a TreeView in WPF. I was successfully able to add and search the tree items for a TreeView which has just one level, but for a TreeView with multiple levels, I am not able to figure out how to access the child controls (`UIElement`) of a TreeViewItem. `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()` returns null when I pass `TreeViewItem.Item` as an argument. I saw few posts which discussed the same issue, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here's my XAML code.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="72*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="SearchTextBox" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
    <TreeView Name="MyTreeView" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding SchoolName}"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Here's my C# code

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}

private void PlanSearchOnSearchInputChanged(string searchQuery)
{
    List<TreeViewItem> items = GetLogicalChildCollection(MyTreeView);
}

public static List<TreeViewItem> GetLogicalChildCollection(TreeView parent)
{
    var logicalCollection = new List<TreeViewItem>();
    foreach (var child in parent.Items)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(child);
        logicalCollection.Add(item);
        GetLogicalChildCollection(item, logicalCollection);
    }
    return logicalCollection;
}

public static List<TreeViewItem> GetLogicalChildCollection(TreeViewItem parent, List<TreeViewItem> logicalCollection)
{
    foreach (var child in parent.Items)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(child);
        logicalCollection.Add(item);
    }
    return logicalCollection;
}
```

PS: I need access to UIElement of the item, not just item.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search WPF Treeview for specific TreeViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754503/search-wpf-treeview-for-specific-treeviewitem)

Comment: This post is quite different from what was asked in the link. I am able to access the items, but what I am not able to get is its UIElement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the TreeViewItem is not expanded then its children will not have any UI so you can't get their children. Maybe that's the problem you're seeing.

This is some code to think about, I don't have all your code to easily work out what's happening but this works on a sample I have. It is quick and dirty rather than super elegant.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in tv.Items)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = tv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
        tvi.IsExpanded = true;
        tvi.UpdateLayout();
        RecurseItem(tvi);
    }
}

private bool gotTheItem = false;
private void RecurseItem(TreeViewItem item)
{
    foreach (var subItem in item.Items)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = item.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(subItem) as TreeViewItem;
        // do something
        if (!gotTheItem)
        {
            RecurseItem(tvi);
        }
    }
}
```

You could set `IsExpanded` back or hook the event fires when you expand an item and probably some other things.

Comment: Haa! Thanks a ton! This was the root cause of my issue. If I manually expand the items and then run my code, its working fine. I tried to set IsExpanded to true and added a delay, but it was still returning null. Anyhow, since I now know the root cause of the issue, I will figure something out to expand the items in code. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Invoking TreeViewItem.UpdateLayout after setting IsExpanded to true did the trick. No need for adding delay:)

Comment: Good point. I'll update my post so that's clear if anyone else comes across this. Clean some of the "dirt" off it.

Answer (score 0):

The TV has a nodes collection. Each node also has a nodes collection.

You need to start at the root, examine each node, and if that node contains a nodes collection with a length > 0, you need to descend into it.

This is typically done with a recursive tree walk.

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.TreeView doesn't have Nodes property. It just has "Items" which I am already using as you can see in the above code.

Comment: wpf TreeView *doesn't* have Nodes. It has Items and their virtualization

Comment: Yes, it has Items, however you are only accessing the first level of Items. See the docs for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-iterate-through-all-nodes-of-a-windows-forms-treeview-control

Comment: No, I am not accessing only the first level of items. There are 2 methods with name "GetLogicalChildCollection". Here, first method iterates through first level of items and while doing so, if any item has child elements, then I am invoking the second method, which iterates through second level of items. My tree has only 2 levels and that's the reason why I stopped there, else I would have made the second method recursive.